# Swagger JAX-RS jersey

Tags: swagger, jax-rs

I have problem with integration of  the swagger in jax rs
I added these dependencies

```
<dependency>
<groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
<artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2</artifactId>
<version>2.1.10</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Dépendance javax.ws.rs-api -->
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
<version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

```
web.xml : 

  <servlet>

    <servlet-name>SwaggerUi</servlet-name>

    <servlet-class>io.swagger.jaxrs.config.DefaultJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>

    <init-param>

        <param-name>openApi.configuration.resourcePackages</param-name>

        <param-value>com.nellarmonia.shuttle.cloud.service</param-value>

    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-name>SwaggerUi</servlet-name>

    <url-pattern>/api/swagger-ui/*</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

```
classe de configuration : 

        classes.add(io.swagger.v3.jaxrs2.integration.resources.OpenApiResource.class);
```

SEVERE: Le Servlet [SwaggerUi] dans l'application web [/My-Jersey-Project] a retourné une exception lors de son chargement
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.swagger.jaxrs.config.DefaultJaxrsConfig

I really nees help
thnk you